# Sort Superclass list of objects that are Subclasses of the Superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, compareto

Suppose I have an abstract Superclass named that is defined like this:

```
public abstract class Member implements Comparable<Member>
```

And then I have two Subclasses of `Member`, defined like this:

```
public class Coach extends Member

public class Player extends Member
```

Then, I have a list of `Member`, which means it contains both `Coach` and `Player`.

I need to sort this list, in which a coach always comes first and then come the players sorted by an identification number.

I need to implement the `compareTo` method to do this. But how do I proceed, knowing that I can't implement the method in the superclass `Member`, since the identification number is a property of `Player` and `Coach` doesn't have it?

I hope I've been clear on the problem.

Comment: As you said, writing the `compareTo()` method on `Member` to sort *child classes* is not possible. You are trying to write a wrong design. In order to compare them, you need to do it processing a common field(s).

Comment: How do you want to compare two coaches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a couple of options here:

- **Write a `compareTo` method on `Member` and write a compator which will check whether member object is the instance of Coach (then it will be always before other `Member` object).**

In this solution, however you assume however that base class will know about it's implementors which might be considered a bad design, as once you start introducing more implementing classes (i.e. `Referee`, `Technical Assistant` etc.) you'll need to change the method every time, and might end up with something really complicated.

On the other hand though you've got the full ordering control in one place, which is easier to test and reason about than...

- **Alternatively extend member with `getOrderingIndicator()` abtract method which you'll implement in both `Player` (assign identification number) and `Coach` (assign 0 or some other value lower than allowed player identification number) and use this abstract method in the `compareTo` method in `Member` class.**

In this solution you'll guarantee that whatever implementations of `Member` base class there are in the future, they will be correctly ordered.

All in all though, I'd strongly suggest implementing the `compareTo` on the member level, since it's the `Member` objects you're comparing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement Comparator and check object's class and take decision

```
abstract class Member implements Comparator<Base>{
    @Override
    public int compare(Base o1, Base o2) {
        if(o1.getClass() == Couch.class && o2.getClass() == Player.class){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        if(o1.getClass() == Player && o2.getClass() == Coach.class){
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }

        if(o1.getClass()==o2.getClass() && o1.getClass() == Coach.class){
            return 0;
        }

        if(o1.getClass() == o2.getClass() && o2.getClass() == Player.class){
            //cast to player and compare them
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: why not "instanceof" instead of getClass()?

Comment: to be strict about that class only

Comment: I see. Fair enough. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

abstract class VIP implements Comparable<Member>{
 abstract  int getOrderIndex();
 abstract String getName();
}


class Member extends VIP {
    String name;
    int index;
    public Member(String s,int i){
    this.name=s;this.index=i;
    }
    
    public  int compareTo(Member m){
       return this.getOrderIndex()-m.getOrderIndex();
     }
    
    public String getName(){
    return name;
    }
    public int getOrderIndex(){
    return index;
    }
}

class Player extends Member {
      public Player(String s,int i){
      super(s,i);
      } 
}
class Coach extends Member{
    public Coach(String s,int i){
      super(s,i);
    }
}
class Refree extends Member{
    public Refree(String s,int i){
      super(s,i);
    }
}

class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Member> l=new ArrayList<Member>();
        
         l.add(new Refree("refree",2));
         l.add(new Player("player2",1));
         l.add(new Player("player1",1));
         l.add(new Coach("coach2",0));       
         l.add(new Coach("coach1",0));      
       
        l.sort((m1,m2)-> m1.compareTo(m2));
       
        l.forEach(o-> System.out.println(o.getName()));
       
       
  }
}
```